# How to build a programs that's output will be used in a Make variable name

Tags: makefile, gnu-make, build-system, build-dependencies

I want to create a Makefile which will build a program which when run's output will be used as a value for a variable in the same Makefile.

Consider the program:

print_name.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
   printf("foo\n");
   return 0;
}
```

I'd like to use the standard output of this program to then determine a directory name to be stored in a variable used in the makefile and used for other rules, so far I've tried:

```
all: $(MY_DIRECTORY_NAME)/my_program

print_name: print_name.c | print_name
    gcc $^ -o $@

MY_DIRECTORY_NAME:=$(shell ./print_name)

$(MY_DIRECTORY_NAME)/my_program: my_program.c 
    mkdir -p $(MY_DIRECTORY_NAME)
    gcc $^ -o $@
```

However when I run:

```
 make all
```

I get:

```
make: *** No rule to make target '/my_program', needed by 'all'.  Stop
```

Whereas I'd like:

```
mkdir -p foo
gcc my_program.c -o foo/my_program
```

So basically, I want to compile `print_name` before the assignment to `MY_DIRECTORY_NAME`, and then that variable in then used in the following rules. Is this possible, and if not are there any workarounds for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic problem is that you need to build (and run) print_name before you can parse the rules that use it -- but all rules are read and parsed before anything is built.  So you need to run make *twice* -- first to build print_name and second to build everything that depends on it.  Something like

```
all: print_name
        $(MAKE) `./print_name`/my_program
```

should do the trick

Comment: Thanks. Hoped that there'd be some for of super lazy initialisation mechanism, but I think you're right. Thanks.